# Understanding JAVA generic keyword 'super'

Tags: java, generics

Recently some people said that I was wrong when I explained why one cannot insert a `Number` object into a list declared as `List<? super RationalNumber>`.
(This assumes that `RationalNumber` is a subclass of `Number`)

My explanation was that in `List<? super RationalNumber>` the `<? super RationalNumber>` stands for an unknown super class of `RationalNumber`. This means that `<? super RationalNumber>` indicates that a valid object for `List<? super RationalNumber>` is an object that extends an unknown super class of `RationalNumber`.

Since an unknown super class of `RationalNumber` is really unknown (e.g. it can be an interface `X` instead of `Number`), there is not guarantee that `Number` is a sub-class of `X` i.e. implements `X`, so `Number` is not a valid substitution of `<? super RationalNumber>`.

What is wrong with this explanation?
Edit: Note that I am asking for what wrong with the way I explain, my explanation. Not another explanation for the original question.

Thanks.

Comment: @rwong Thanks, I know how people explain it. I don't understand what is wrong with my explanation and how I explain it.

Comment: everything I said is in the context of a List. I will edit my question

Comment: I think I get what you mean now. I will try to see things in the same way of the link you post.

Answer (score 7):

`List<? super RationalNumber>` is a list of some type X that is a superclass of RationalNumber.  Your assumption is that `RationalNumber` is a subclass of `Number`, so the possible candidates for X are `RationalNumber`, `Number`, or `Object`.  The most restrictive possibility is that X is `RationalNumber` itself.  A `List<RationalNumber>` can contain only instances of RationalNumber, and cannot contain instances of `Number`.

In short, a `List<? super T>` is a list that can accept instances of T, but the current contents are of unknown type.  This contrasts with `List<? extends T>`, which contains instances of T, but does not allow adding new elements because the type accepted is unknown.

This example illustrates the use of `super`:

```
void storePies(List<? super RationalNumber> list) { 
    list.add(new RationalNumber(22, 7))
    list.add(new RationalNumber(355, 113))
}

...
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();
storePies(list);
list.add(3.14159265358979);
```

This example illustrates the use of `extends`:

```
double sum(Collection<? extends Number> numbers) {
    double s = 0;
    for (Number n: numbers) { s += n.doubleValue(); }
    return s;
}

List<Integer> somePrimes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
somePrimes.add(5);
somePrimes.add(17);
double total = sum(somePrimes);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have just edited my question for better clarification.

Answer (score 5):

See also:

- [Lower-bounded wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html)
- the answers to the question *[java generics super keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3847162/377657)* on Stackoverflow.

---

<sub>A digression. Feel free to skip.</sub>

For programmers who are also familiar with C#, a similar feature exists:

- [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

The terms, covariance and contravariance, can be traced back to the early discussions coming from the [Liskov substitution principle (LSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

---

The design goal of lower-bounded wildcard (LBWC) is to ensure the type safety of the following piece of code.

(This is just one example; one of the very simple example among others.)

```
List<? super RationalNumber> containerOne = new ArrayList<RationalNumber>(); 
List<? super RationalNumber> containerTwo = new ArrayList<Number>(); 
List<? super RationalNumber> containerThree = new ArrayList<Object>(); 

RationalNumber itemValue = new RationalNumber(22, 7); 

containerOne.add(itemValue); 
containerTwo.add(itemValue); 
containerThree.add(itemValue);
```

---

In short, LBWC allows the ***"handles"*** - generic classes having an LBWC (`containerOne`, `containerTwo`, `containerThree` in the above sample) to:

- Be assigned instances of the generic class (of type parameter `T`) whenever it is known that `RationalNumber` can be safely up-cast to `T`.

---

Now, we use this knowledge and try to answer the question: can we pass in a `Number` to such a **"handle"** - a generic class having an LBWC of `RationalNumber`?

---

Given that

- It is valid to assign an instance of `new List<RationalNumber>()` to a handle of `List<? super RationalNumber> varGeneric`.
- Of course it is valid to do something entirely different; but the design of LBWC is that this is *the* situation that it needs to deal with.

We obtain this corollary question:

- Can we call `new List<RationalNumber>().add(new Number(...))` ?

  - ***Of course not.***

---

Seeing that it is LBWC's design goal to prevent this from happening, one can derive this conclusion:

- If LBWC is designed to be enforceable at all (by the compiler, or language police), it must prevent this assignment (passing in a `Number` for a type `?` for which the LBWC is `RationalNumber`) from happening.

---

This answers the question from a design perspective. The matter of enforcement can only be answered by senior members of the community who are familiar with the construction of the Java language and its compiler tools. Comments from the general crowd will only provide speculations, or "hypotheses" or "theories".